# Strange output after calling unset()

Tags: php

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) for NULL says that if I called `unset()` on a variable, the variable will become NULL:

> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> it has been assigned the constant NULL.
>
> it has not been set to any value yet.
>
> **it has been unset().**

However, this [tutorial](http://code.iamkate.com/php/references-tutorial/) says the following will happen when calling `unset()` on a variable:

> PHP looks in the symbol table to find the zval corresponding to this
>   variable, decrements the refcount, and removes the variable from the
>   symbol table. Because the refcount is now zero, the garbage collector
>   knows that there is no way of accessing this zval, and can free the
>   memory it occupies.

Now I tried the following code:

```
<?php
    $x = 12345;
    unset($x);
    echo gettype($x);
?>
```

The output I got is strange, I got an error that says that the variable is undefined (which conforms with the second quote I have posted), but I also got the type of the variable which is NULL (which conforms with the first quote I have posted):

[image]

Why am I getting this strange output?

Comment: because you have unset the variable means it is completely destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

> unset() destroys the specified variables.

It does not make the Variable **NULL**  so the warning absolutely makes sense

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: x
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: The documentation says that if I called `unset()` on a variable, the variable will become NULL. Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: where it says `the variable will become NULL` ?

Answer (score 1):

**unset()** destroys the specified variables. Note that in `PHP 3`, **unset()** will always return `TRUE` (actually, the integer value 1). In `PHP 4`, however, **unset()** is *no longer a true function: it is now a statement*. As such no value is returned, and attempting to take the value of **unset()** results in a *parse error*