# Why does gettype() output "NULL" for an undefined variable?

Tags: php

I have tried the following code:

```
<?php
    echo gettype($x);
?>
```

And I got the following output:

[image]

Why did `gettype()` outputted "NULL" after the error was displayed? I mean an undefined variable is a variable that doesn't exist and not a NULL variable, right?

Comment: where is your variable value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange output after calling unset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292182/strange-output-after-calling-unset)

Comment: Where do you define `$x`?

Comment: @Phil Roggenbuck I intended `$x` to be undefined.

Comment: @Steve ah now i get it ok.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) explains:

> The special `NULL` value represents a variable with no value. `NULL` is the only possible value of type `null`.
>
> A variable is considered to be `null` if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant `NULL`.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Also check the table ["Comparisons of $x with PHP functions"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: But if a variable that hasn't been set to any value yet is NULL (like the documentation says), then why am I getting an error when I call `gettype()` on the variable (I should only get "NULL")?

Comment: `gettype()` returns `NULL` when asked about the type of an undefined variable but any reading of an undefined variable issues "Notice: Undefined variable".

Answer (score 0):

You kinda did answer your own question.
At the moment you're trying to get the type of nothing it will be null by default.

For example
X = 5
It will return a integer

But in your case x wasn't initiated and therefore it stays null.
Vars work on the run and can be anything.

I hope this is somehow useful.

(if this contains a misconception please let me know what is wrong)